# React Native Formik - Error at passing Object to HandleChange

Tags: react-native, onchange, formik

I'm trying to save an Object on form.values to work with it later on a Query.

The problem is, even I have used it on another project, this time it gives this error:

[image: Formik's handleChange error]

Does anyone have some clue about this?

The specific line I'm inputting this is this one:
`onChange={form.handleChange('MultipleSelect')({})}`

I'm not sure, but I think it is not finding the '_eventOrTextValue' function...

I have tried passing integers, objects, arrays, but the only kind of value it accepts is string...
Oddly I used this same mirrored function on another project the same way...

Comment: Show me the whole sauce of this part

Comment: That's pretty much it. Any value another than a String passed to the function brings the same error.
Comparing to an old version of Formik, I noticed that the function has been changed, from accepting any value and returning a function, to just receiving a value of type String or an event, and returning nothing.
So I used the setFieldValue function from Formik, and it worked fine.
I don't know if it's a bug, but anyway I opened a Issue on the Formik's GitHub repository.